# How to send List of any T type from Android to Flutter side by using Method Channels?

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to retrieve some contacts with additional info like name and id from native side to Flutter. But List of any Custom Type is not allowed. 
Can someone suggest the solution.?

On Android side---

```
 if (methodCall.method.equals("fetch_contacts")) {
        List<Contact> contactList = getContacts();
        result.success(contactList);
 } else {
        result.notImplemented();
  }
```

On Flutter Side--

```
List<dynamic> contactsList = await methodChannel.invokeListMethod('fetch_contacts');
```

Above android side code is giving IllegalStateException as its can't send Contact model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Contact` is a Java object, so cannot be sent across the method channel. What would it turn into at the Dart end? You could create a Dart class, also called `Contact`, but even then you couldn't send it. You need to define a way to serialize/deserialize the objects into parts that *will* traverse the method channel. (See [StandardMessageCodec](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/services/StandardMessageCodec-class.html) for the basic objects that can cross.)

Here are some possible ways to serialize your object:

- JSON - you could turn it into JSON in Java, send a list of Strings across the method channel and then decode those strings into a list of Dart objects. (Or send a single JSON string representing the list of objects.)
- Maps - you could turn each object into a map of string-value pairs (the values would need to be of one of the acceptable types - see the link above) and send a list of maps.

Comment: Yes, I solved the issue by using a list of JsonObject. As I can decode json at dart end. And this List of JsonObject can be send by converting them to string.
By the way, thanks for the help buddy!